# SAS Nested Likelihood Ratio Test for a Logistic Model

Tags: logistic-regression, sas

Using SAS Studio (online, student version)...
Need to do a "nested likelihood ratio test" for a logistic regression. 
Entirety of instructions are: "Perform a nested likelihood ratio test comparing your full model (all predictors included)to a reduced model of interest."
The two models I have are:

```
Proc Logistic Data=Project_C;
Model Dem (event='1') = VEP TIF Income NonCit Unemployed Swing;
Run;
```

and

```
Proc Logistic Data=Project_C;
Model Dem (Event='1') = VEP TIF Income / clodds=Wald clparm=Wald expb rsquare;
Run;
```

I honestly have no idea where to even start. 
Any suggestions would be appreciated. 
Thanks!